# Not able to handle executeFetchRequest error

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

My fetch request works fine and I get my fetched objects without any problems. What I want to do, is handle the error in case the entity doesn't exist. The problem is, I can't handle the error because the app crashes when I call executeFetechRequest: error: without any warnings.

My fetch looks like:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Info" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"infoID" ascending:YES]];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"infoID like %@",[a substringFromIndex:13]];
request.predicate = predicate;
request.fetchBatchSize = 1;

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (error == nil) {
    ...
}
else {
    //handle error
}
```

As I said, there's no problem as long as the entity exists, but I want to handle the error if it doesn't exist. Any idea? Cheers

Comment: Umm.. you should never be doing a fetch request for an entity type that doesn't exist. In what circumstance would you ever need to do this?

Comment: Actually good question :/ ... I thought I need to check it in case of sync between apps of different versions, but I actually catch this case in a different way. Thanks haha ... but to be 100% sure, why not check if the entity exists so the app doesn't crash?

Comment: Again this should never happen, you should only reference entities that you know exist. If you update the app to  remove this entity, then you should alter your code to no longer use it. You should have your Core Data model set up to do versioning so that you can migrate your database easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask the model if such entity is present:

```
    NSArray *entities = managedObjectModel.entities;
    BOOL canExecute=NO;
    for(NSEntityDescription *ed in entities) {
       // check if entity name is equal to the one you are looking for
       if(found) {
          canExecute=YES;
          break;
       }
    }

   if(canExecute) {
     // execute your request and all the rest...
   } else {
     NSLog(@"Entity description not found");
   }
```

if doesn't exist you don't execute the fetch reuest